File creation in Cloudflare Pages
I am trying to make a basic cloudflare page which has a form to submit new directories onto the site. I want to create a simple node server (or any other language that would work for this) that would create that directories with the corresponding name.
(Since cloudflare doesnt support hosting servers on the pages.dev domain I'm not sure if this is even possible, so I was wondering if there were any other alternatives for free hosting that would support this?)
many thanks
